# Eclipse is complaining about "The import java.util.List cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, import

This is a strange one I don't understand. I am using Eclipse to work on a spring project. Eclipse started validation of my project in the background suddenly and it seemed to take *forever*. I couldn't save my work or quit Eclipse until the validation has finished. As the operation was taking forever and looked stuck to me, I had to terminate Eclipse. When I restarted Eclipse, my project seems funny - Eclipse had troubles linking my imports.

For example, I had a java file with some imports:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Out of these imports, `import java.util.List;` is the only line that has red curvy lines below. When my cursor hovers above it, it gives me this error:

```
The import java.util.List cannot be resolved
```

This certainly looks strange to me. How can Eclipse recognise `java.util.ArrayList` and alike, but not `java.util.List`?

I checked my project properties: Java Build Path > Libraries
Under Modulepath, I have "JRE System Library [JavaSE-11]". I tried to change that to "JRE System Library [JavaSE-17]", but nothing changes. I guess it is not a problem with my JRE System Library...

I just wonder if my Eclipse is corrupted, or my JRE/JDK broken, or something else...

Comment: Have you tried to compile from command line?

Comment: @Hulk It does compile and build correctly.

Comment: Try `Project -> Clean` and make sure `Build automatically` is checked.

Comment: @user2526586 then the problem is limited to Eclipse. Try any clean/refresh options you can think of.

Comment: Are the v11 and v17 JREs set on your *Installed JREs* preference page still valid? Updates can change paths, and you haven't said much about the system you're on.

Comment: If this is a Maven project, try Maven->Update project.

Comment: If other options don't work, try to open the same project in another workspace as well.